# WPF 3D to 2D projection appears wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, projection

Have a case where a point on the PerspectiveCamera’s LookDirection vector does not project to the center of the Viewport3D. Any thoughts as to why?

Here are details of the case: The Viewport3D is 778, 405. Any visible Point3D the camera is looking directly at would project to (389, 202.5). The PerspectiveCamera is located at (1379.4, -577.7, 0.7).

In the first case the center of the White sphere is (13,080.3,-6,491.9,-407.9) which is 13,117 units from the camera. Camera’s LookDirection is (0.89, -0.45, -0.03). The White sphere projects to the visual center of the Viewport3D. MathUtils.TryWorldToViewportTransform reports the sphere’s center point projects to (389, 202.5), as expected. The black lines are added to show the center of the Viewport3D.

First case screen shot here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Cc8ch2uYWUjWgoSV6

In the second case the center of the Blue sphere is (1,383.0,-579.6, 0.3) which is 4.1 units from the camera. Camera’s LookDirection is (0.88,-0.46,-0.11). The Blue sphere does NOT render to the visual center of the Viewport3D. MathUtils.TryWorldToViewportTransform reports the center point being projected to (389, 202.5), as expected. Visually though the blue sphere is not drawing at center, it is at more like (295, 303).

Second case screen shot here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/1RfZh6uvjfEinaiA7

Placing the camera at the 4.1 distance from the White sphere it projects correctly to the center of the Viewport3D. The difference is that the White sphere is further from the (0, 0, 0) origin than the Blue sphere.

The Blue sphere will project more correctly to the center of the Viewport3D if the camera is “far away” from it, like out near the White sphere.

The Blue sphere is mathematically positioned to be at the center of the Viewport3D. Any thoughts as to why the Blue sphere is not rendering at the center of the Viewport3D in the second case above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I manually calculate the camera direction, I get the following values:

```
Blue sphere:   1383.0,    -579.6,      0.3
Camera:        1379.4,    -577.7,      0.7
Difference:       3.6,      -1.9,      0.4
Normalized:  0.880146, -0.464521, 0.097794
```

That's very close to your look direction *(0.88,-0.46,-0.11)*, but not the same. It's not a rounding error, because the Z direction is two digits out. Based on the values you've posted, the blue sphere is **not** mathematically positioned to be at the center of the Viewport3D.

You say that manually calculating the position with `MathUtils.TryWorldToViewportTransform` gives you the expected result. This part has me puzzled. The only explanation I can think of is maybe the the LookDirection (and corresponding transformation matrixes) that you posted are stale values, and the `MathUtils` library recalculates it all on demand so it gets the correct values.

Comment: Hi, TY for the response. The values are not stale, I am sure of that. The LookDirection Z value is -0.10950268842253731, all the values were rounded for brevity in the post.

Comment: Using the non-rounded numbers I am pretty sure the Blue sphere is mathematically positioned to be at the center of the Viewport3D. But it does not render there. Wonder if there might be rounding issues deeper in WPF of which we should be aware of?

Comment: Your look direction's Z is out by more than a rounding error. Compare `0.097794` to `0.10950268842253731`. I suggest you add a line to manually calculate the look direction, and compare that to the camera's LookDirection property to see if you can reproduce it

Comment: Andrew, See the case at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1365779/wpf-3d-to-2d-projection-appears-wrong. It has more info from digging into these "rounding conditions" being encountered.  Pls check it out and pass along any comments or suggestions. TY!

Comment: @WoodManEXP that answer from Hui Liu doesn't seem correct to me. If you are looking directly at an object, it should *always* be in the centre of the viewport. The distortion caused by a perspective transform may change the scale of the object in the X or Y directions, but it will not move it away from the centre (unless you're using something special like a tilted projection)

Comment: Could you add in the Model, View and Projection matrices you are using, and the parameters you're passing when creating the projection matrix? It might help to reproduce the matrices and see if the projection matrix is as expected

Comment: Andrew, Agreed “If you are looking directly at an object, it should always be in the centre of the viewport.”
In MS’s WPF 3D system rather than create the matrices, one creates a 3D model and a ProjectionCamera located in 3D space including LookDirection and UpDirection vectors. WPF then maintains the matrices projecting the camera’s view onto a 2D frame called a Viewport3D. The “LookDirection Test” VS project shows this, including the projection error, as a small C# project.

Comment: From my investigation it appears WPF is correctly projecting the 3D onto 2D world coords. Somewhere after that though something converts the 2D world coords to screen pixel coordinates and is making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research into WPF’s 3D capabilities (using the Viewport3D control to render 3D) including reverse engineering parts of the WPF Viewport3D source code, the best way forward has been to give up using WPF’s 3D subsystem. It does not offer a usable means of dealing with or controlling, among others, the 3D to 2D projection problems baked into it.

Fortunately, a WPF OpenGL C# binding is available, it is called OpenTK and can be nicely woven into the WPF framework. Can be found at http://opentk.net.

OpenGL is somewhat of a paradigm shift from WPF’s 3D. It, at first, feels more tedious to learn and use. Once getting into the Zen of OpenGL though it is, IMHO, a nice improvement.  It provides excellent control of the many things that are hard to control in WPF 3D, including the 3D to 2D projection issues.

OpenGL seems to offer better performance in terms of both processing and memory utilization.

WPF 3D’s hit testing will be missed though. It is baked more into WPF 3D’s object model, not the case with OpenGL…